# How to turn off vectorization in opt (LLVM)

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, vectorization

I'm struggling with understanding inner works of polly (polyhedral optimizer for LLVM) and I'm stuck at a problem: I know how to turn off vectorization in Clang (-fno-vectorize command option does it), but doing the same in opt eludes me. Documentation shows only how to turn this pass ON, not off. The only way to omit it is, as far as I know, using clang, which can't print stats of passes (or I couldn't find how to).
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

I'm using the following commands to run the programs:

```
clang -Xclang -load -Xclang ~/llvm_build/tools/polly/Debug+Asserts/lib/LLVMPolly.so -O3 -fno-vectorize -mllvm -polly -mllvm -polly-vectorizer=polly -S -emit-llvm in.c -o out.ll
opt -load ~/{Polly shared lib}.so -O3 -polly -polly-vectorizer=polly -stats in.ll -o out.ll
```

First one omits clang vectorization, but does not print stats, second prints stats, but uses the vectorization I don't want.

Comment: try `opt -load ~/{Polly shared lib}.so -O0 -polly -polly-vectorizer=polly -stats in.ll -o out.ll`

Comment: opt does not take `-O0` as an argument, the minimum is `-O1`

Comment: And `O1` includes vectorization ?

Comment: All LLVM compilations include vectorization, from what I understood from the documentation page ("The Loop Vectorizer is enabled by default, but it can be disabled through clang using the command line flags"). Docs mention disabling it in clang, but not in opt.

Answer (score 1):

The proven way is to check the sources: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/opt/opt.cpp.

You are looking for `opt -disable-loop-vectorization ...`.